# What supervised machine learning algorithm to classify words in Python?

Tags: python, supervised-learning

I am working with a problem where I receive a free-text field where a user describes the attributes of the car it is selling. I want to make this into structured pre-defined attributes.

An example is that in the field for tires the customer could write:

- studded tyres
- spike tires
- spiked tires

These should result in my pre-defined attribute: studded tires

Hence, I would feed my training model with:

```
╔═════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Free text input ║    Answer     ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ studded tyres   ║ studded tires ║
║ spike tires     ║ studded tires ║
║ spiked tires    ║ studded tires ║
╚═════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Since I have to make the classifications for the training data by myself I wont have that many observations.

What machine learning algorithm in Python would you recommend in my case?

Edit - The language the application is runnig on is not English. Hence, I cant use any methods that relies on English dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to apply supervised learning you, in most cases, need a relatively large set of data. Therefore I think it might be more useful to use [Fuzzy/Approximate string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching), where strings are compared using the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

A python package that does fuzzy string matching is [FuzzyWuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy), which you can install with:

```
pip install fuzzywuzzy
```

Then you can use it to get for example the two most equal strings to the user input:

```
>>> from fuzzywuzzy import process
>>> choices = ['tires', 'doors', 'windows']
>>> userInput = 'spiked tires'
>>> process.extract(userInput, choices, limit=2)
[('tires', 90), ('doors', 36)]
```

For more information see [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/2456/198).

---

*Edit:* Another (maybe not optimal) method could be a [Naive Bayes classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) which calculate the probability of a class based on the features.

In python you can use [textblob](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/classifiers.html), which uses which words are in the string as feature:

> By default, the NaiveBayesClassifier uses a simple feature extractor that indicates which words in the training set are contained in a document.
>
> For example, the sentence “I feel happy” might have the features contains(happy): True or contains(angry): False.

you can install by:

```
pip install textblob
```

and to get the corpora data:

```
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

Then using the data:

```
train = [ ('studded tyres', 'studded tires'), ('spike tires', 'studded tires'), ('spiked tires', 'studded tires'), ('blinded windows', 'windows'), ('widows', 'windows') ]
test = [('studded tyres', 'studded tires'), ('dark windows', 'windows'), ('big window', 'windows')]
```

Then you can train it:

```
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train)
```

and use it to predict a category:

```
>>> cl.classify('big windows')
'windows'
>>> cl.classify('big tir')
'studded tires'
>>> cl.classify('widows')
'windows'
>>> cl.classify('big window')
'studded tires'
```

And as accuracy (using `test`) it gives:

```
>>> cl.accuracy(test)
0.6666666666666666
```

For small data sets this might not work well, also with incorrectly written words there are problems (if they not occur often).

Also see: [A simple explanation of Naive Bayes Classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059594/a-simple-explanation-of-naive-bayes-classification)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I would have a larger dataset, what supervised learning method would you recommend?

Comment: Logistic Regression works well with words